# How can I use a Maven project as a dependency to another Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, mercurial

I'm new to Maven, therefore, sorry in advance if my question is too general. I have a Maven project, call it `projectA`, which resides in my company's Mercurial repository (let's call it `https://hg.mycompany.com/niceprojects/`). Recently, I built a separate Maven project, call it `projectB` in the same repository. I now want to use in `projectB` some classes that I have in `projectA`. The directory structure in the repository is currently:

```
-----niceprojects
       |
       |__projectA
       |     |__pom.xml
       |
       |__projectB
             |__pom.xml
```

What is a neat way of doing this? I would like to avoid manually building `projectA`, then adding its jars in `projectB`. I would also like to keep the same directory structure. Step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: `projectA` have to be installed in your repository and then declare a dependency to `projectA` in `projectB`'s pom.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general advice when using Maven is to use a Maven Repository Manager such as Nexus.

In this case Nexus has the addtional benefit that it can host your jars.

So I advice to do the following:

- Configure a CI (e.g. Jenkins) job to build projectA and deploy the JAR to your Nexus instance
- Declare projectA as a dependency in projectB

When building projectB, it can download the projectA JAR from your Nexus instance without you having to build projectA yourself.

Comment: You beat me to the Nexus recommendation. A sidenote I wanted to add to my answer was that the requested step-by-step instructions can literally fill several chapters of a book, so that is a bit too much to ask.